# how to configure a custom view in Android Studio Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I didn't find hot to get a custom view in Android Studio logcat.
When I run a whatever application I get in every row of logcat something like that:

01-13 16:12:42.214 31447-31467/com.me.myproject I/mypackage.myclassname﹕ MyLogMessage

I'd like to customize the view, for example I'd like to not see this part:
"01-13 16:12:42.214 31447-31467/com.me.myproject I/mypackage.myclassname" and see for example only"MyLogMessage".
Any suggestion?

Thank you
Fausto